# How not to print a new line with echo (and wc) in a shell script?

Tags: shell-script

I have done this script :

```
#! /bin/sh  
path="foo" 
while touch $path ; do 
    path=./${path} 
done 

echo "echec avec le nom $path qui fait" 
echo $path|wc -c 
echo "caracteres"
```

How can I print on the same line the 3 echo lines?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To suppress the newline with the `echo` used on linux systems<sup>1</sup>, use `-n`:

```
echo -n "echec avec le nom $path qui fait"
```

However, `wc` also prints a newline, and that can't be suppressed, but it can be discarded:

```
size=$(echo $path | wc -c);
echo "echec avec le nom $path qui fait $((size-1)) caracteres"
```

I've used `$((size-1))` here because `wc` will have counted the newline output by echo.  You could instead use `size=$(echo -n $path | wc -c)`, but beware the caveat about the non-standardness of `-n`.

---

<sup>1. The `-n` implemented by GNU coreutil's echo is non-standard, so YMMV.  Fortunately, you don't actually need to use it here.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your response, but $size isn't printed (there is a blank instead).

Comment: You've done something wrong.  Try on the commandline `size=$(echo "hello world" | wc -c); echo "Size is $size"`  If that doesn't output `Size is 12`, your computer has been possessed by aliens, etc.

Comment: It outputs "Size is 12"...

Comment: But this :
path="fooo" 
$size=$(echo $path | wc -c);
echo "echec avec le nom $path qui fait $size caracteres" 

prints "echec avec le nom foo qui fait  caracteres"

Comment: **Don't use `$` with the variable name in the declaration/assignment.**  I.e., `size=`, not `$size=`. You can actually do this: `echo "echec avec le nom $path qui fait $(echo -n $path | wc -c) caracteres"`.  I've thrown an `-n` in there because `wc` counts the newline otherwise, but I've also edited in another method to deal with that above (see last paragraph).

Comment: Note that *echo* will most likely be a shell builtin, not the *echo* from coreutils.

Comment: `wc -c` counts bytes, not characters. Just as well since character encodings are not enforced for file names. If you know file names are encoded in the current locale, you can use `wc -m` to count the characters.

Comment: With many `echo` implementations, that won't work properly if `$path` contains backslash characters (try with `_path='/tmp/\ctest'` with various shells/echo).

Answer (score 10):

It would be far better if you didn't use `echo` at all. The use of `echo` when combined with arbitrary input can have unintended effects. What's more, you do not need `wc` to count the characters in a shell variable - the shell can do it just as well and without execing a separate process to boot.

For example:

with `wc`:

```
_path=/some/place/in/my/filesystem
printf %s "$_path" | wc -c

###OUTPUT###
28
```

no `wc`:

```
printf %s "${#_path}"

###OUTPUT###
28
```

two `printf` arguments:

```
printf 'Arg char count:\t%s\nArg contents:\t%s\n' \                                                                    
    "${#_path}" "$_path"

###OUTPUT###
Arg char count: 28
Arg contents:   /some/place/in/my/filesystem
```

your command:

```
printf 'echec avec le nom %s qui fait %s caracteres\n' \
    "$_path" "${#_path}"

###OUTPUT###
echec avec le nom /some/place/in/my/filesystem qui fait 28 caracteres
```

See [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/52934) and the spec on [POSIX parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The `-n` option with `echo` suppresses newline.  So, you can do:

```
echo -n "echec avec le nom $path qui fait" 
echo -n $(echo $path|wc -c)
echo "caracteres"
```

Comment: `wc` will still output a newline this way.

Comment: Yes, use @goldilock's method to suppress newline from `wc`